# How can I recover these hidden files?

Tags: ubuntu, data-recovery

I made my Windows 7 hard drive unbootable (don't ask how right now, I was being stupid :P), and am running Ubuntu from a CD to backup the files before I do a system restore. The only problem is, the only files I really care about the most, my Finale .mus files, are hidden. And I try to add read and write permissions from Ubuntu, but they just disappear. I'm pretty sure they did the same thing in Win7, too, which is why they're still hidden. Probably related to those stupid personalized folders. But how do I get around this?? I'm not that familiar with Linux.

Answer (score 0):

How do you define 'hidden'? Do they have prepended dots in their names? Seeing as you were originally using Windows, it seems unlikely.

```
# find /mnt/hdd/ | grep -i .mus
```

Change /mnt/hdd to the folder where your Windows harddrive is mounted, the command should return any files with '.mus' in them.

Comment: Either that won't find any, or I'm doing it wrong. Basically, in Windows, I couldn't see those files (in a folder named "compositions") except IN Finale. I'd open Finale and they'd be there and openable, but browsing windows explorer, they'd disappear.

Comment: You you remember where on the c: drive the compositions folder was located?

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu go to the location of hidden file and Press `Ctrl+h`. It should show the hidden files.